# how to call remote page in div?

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is my code for taking external page into div using ajax
what i tried is i clicked on button i must display the response in div
but i tried several times but doesn't works.
my javascript code is

```
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

function ajaxinclude(url) {
    var url=rootdomain+url;
    alert(url);
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
try {
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
} 
catch (e){
try{
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
catch (e){}
}
}
else
return false
page_request.open('GET', url, false) //get page synchronously 
page_request.send(null)
writecontent(page_request)
}

function writecontent(page_request){
if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || page_request.status==200)
document.getElementById("eee").innerHTML=(page_request.responseText);
}
```

and this is my body section :-----

```
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxinclude('/songcake/index.php')" value="Click !" />
<div id="eee" style=" width:400px; height:800px;">
</div>
```

please help

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach your method to `onreadystatechange` which not there in your code

```
 page_request.onreadystatechange = writecontent;

 function writecontent() {
   if (page_request.readyState != 4)  { return; }
   document.getElementById("eee").innerHTML=(page_request.responseText);

 }
```

Comment: I don't think innerHTML is supported on all browsers.

Comment: writecontent(page_request) replace this line with page_request.onreadystatechange = writecontent; and copy the function pasted by me in your code

Comment: thanks for the response but its doesn't work properly.
actually when i entered in my code it doesn't work ,please suggest solution.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but will u please ur gmail id so that while chatting i can clear idea...
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery and you can just do something like

```
$.get('/songcake/index.php', function(data) { $("#eee").html(data); });
```

Comment: Even if I agree you, do you really think that a 20kb+ library is appropriate only for ONE AJAX call? :)

Comment: @lonut: Why simply reference jQuery from the Google CDN? That way the script will nearly always have been cached before even arriving at the site?